# Code Repository Retention Best Practice?

Tags: git

We recently started migrating a ton of small apps from our legacy Lotus Notes system to SharePoint and other internal web applications. In doing so, our developers have been spinning up lots and lots of repositories in our Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) work space, many of which are single-use migration applications. Developers have expressed a desire to keep these repositories in case they need to reference the code in the future, but it is unlikely that the code in the repository itself will be needed again.

With that said, I'm concerned at how mucked up our database of repositories will be, and how hard it will be to differentiate between the important code and non-important code. Is there a best practice for handling these sorts of repositories? Should I do a yearly audit on these to determine if they are still relevant or not? When do you decide to delete a repository? None of this information I can find on Google, so I'm curious to hear how many of you handle it.

Comment: You make this decision the same way you make it when you spring-clean your house.  Are you ever going to need that 30 year old gadget?

Comment: And if you do have reasons to keep old projects that are not actively used, why not move the repositories to a separate 'archive' area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"We recently started migrating"*  sounds like we are not talking about very old code here.  Furthermore, *"a ton of small apps from our legacy"* suggests a high complexity and time pressure.

So, there are some good arguments to listen to your developers:

- In a couple of weeks, you might experience problems because of unexpected use cases or interactions, or errors during the migration that only affect rare situations. It will then be faster to analyse the problem with the mapping in the migration tools at hand.  And perhaps it will be necessary to remigrate or update subparts of some migrated data structures.  It would be a pity to restart from scratch.
- Perhaps have your developers already identified some pieces of algorithms that could be reused.  After all, it's the same data.
- There could be some legal reasons that require for audit purpose your migration programmes to be kept for some time (e.g. if the legacy apps relate somehow to finance,  or if you're in a sector that underlies the [GMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_manufacturing_practice), such as in the pharmaceutical industry)

Finally, what will happen if you decide on your own to get rid of the migration code despite the firm requests of your developers and it later turns out that it was a bad idea ?

Looking at the cost of storage and the risks mentioned above, I'd suggest to listen to your developers.  This doesn't prevent you to go for a solution that satisfies everybody, such as for example keeping the code but moving it to a separate repository; you could after some month archive it, before throwing it away for good if the archives remain unaccessed for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with VSTS specifically, but in github these sorts of temporary repos are usually put in the developer's personal profile (like [mine here](https://github.com/kbielefe?tab=repositories)), instead of the organization's repos (like [my company's here](https://github.com/ADTRAN)).  Then if a personal project becomes a company product, you can promote it later.

The personal repos are just as powerful as the organization ones.  You can give specific other developers push access, accept pull requests against it, etc.  Developers can create them without permission, and can keep them as long or as short as they like, without polluting the list of  organization repos.

As your repos have already been promoted to the organization area, I would just tell your developers they have a week to fork it into their personal profile before it will be deleted.  Then the decision of whether and how long to keep it is decentralized.